# Multiple commands produce error in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode13

I have been stuck on this bug for quite a while now so any help would be appreciated. When I try to build my app I keep getting the following build error:

Multiple commands produce '/Users/my_user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Expense_Tracker_Final-aujeprcwgnjmizeaueitvhpegrzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Expense Tracker Final.app':

1. Target 'Expense Tracker Final' has create directory command with output '/Users/my_user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Expense_Tracker_Final-aujeprcwgnjmizeaueitvhpegrzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Expense Tracker Final.app'
2. That command depends on command in Target 'Expense Tracker Final': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

I have tried solution that have been recommended on other stack overflow questions such as deleting certain files from the [CP] Copy Pods Resources, but nothing seems to be working. Could someone please help me I'm really lost.

Comment: I'd probably remove/deintegrate everything related to CocoaPods and then start the CocoaPods process over (init, etc)

Comment: Don't know who has downgraded this question and for what reason. I also keep getting this error from time to time and none of the available solutions across the stack traces has worked. The only thing which could help (sometime) is "product  -> Clean Build Folder"

Comment: A "Clean Build Folder" fixed that for me

Answer (score 67):

Select Targets -> BuildPhases.

There you saw Copy Bundle Resources. Just remove the duplicate file that is creating an error by selecting that file and clicking on the minus icon and if info.plist is present there just remove it also.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any duplicate files though all the files there are unique

Comment: And what about info.plist file is it available there or not?

Comment: Thank-you. Removing the info.plist there resolved my duplicate info.plist problem.

Comment: @SaurabhPathak do i need to delete Googleservice-info.plist ?,bcs i don't see any other info.plist file here

Comment: Thank you for the picture (and the correct solution)

Answer (score 18):

In my case, this happens because there are 2 files that have the same name. So the solution is just to rename one of the files' name

Comment: Keep coming back to this thread thinking: "there's no duplicate, I'm sure of it!"... after a while looking at other possible issues, there's the duplicate file...

Comment: I my case I've got a duplicate in the Recovered references folder after git merge.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem while archiving the project, The above solution didn't work for me, after spending some time i finally found the solution.

- **Delete `React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources` in the Pods project and it worked.**

[image: steps to remove React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources]

Comment: it's worked but why create multiple time ??

Comment: @JitendrasinhZala you found the reason why its happening? The problem is everytime pod install is done these files get regenerated, so any way you found for a permanent fix for this issue?

Comment: it's worked for me, but these files get regenerated.

Comment: I haven't find any solution to that yet , so until then you have to delete the file.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there's a duplicate code in your script under **Build Phase** >  **[CP] Copy Pods Resources**
Remove the duplicate and re-run the project.

Answer (score 3):

This error is coming from the IOS directory because there are some duplicate files Build Phase > [CP] Copy Pods Resources, in my case the project was building on Android only and throwing this error for IOS.

I fixed this by first backing up the IOS directory, then deleting the IOS directory
then ran this command:

flutter create -i swift . --project-name="your project Name"

NOTE: check pubspec.yaml for your project name

A new podfile will be created, open it and uncomment this line of code
platform :ios, '9.0'
remember to replace the '9.0' with '10.0'

after running the command do
cd .
then do
flutter run

Answer (score 3):

My issue is fixed by removing the duplicated file (reported by the error message) in the Build Phase > Embed Frameworks.

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Targets -> BuildPhases**.

It shows which file is being duplicated, in the error message that you're shown.

**For example:**
*Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ckjnwutcwrniytbresvlcsobapny/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'*

It's not necessarily the **Info.plist** file. It's **GoogleService-Info.plist** in this case.
You can remove this file from the BuildPhases and your app will run as usual :)

Comment: this. I had a copy of GoogleService-Info.plist saved on my desktop, and for some reason "Copy Bundle Resources" was listing it. Removed it, worked

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to build phase to make the change it worked for me, after that you delete all the copied files

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your pod version `pod --version.`
2. Update Coacoapods to latest version - `v1.5.3`
3. if it's not, by running `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.5.3`
4. Update all your pods by running `pod update`
5. Remove duplicate info.plist file from `Target`>`Build` `Phases`> Copy
   Bundle Resources
   if any.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the duplicated file in [CP] Copy Pods Resources
Output Files, then it didn't show this error again.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are facing this after resolving conflict or issues in .pbxproj file using Kin or any other tool.

like every one said check in your Build Phase but in my case instead of duplicate files in any of the phase I have duplicate phases. In the picture below I have two "[CP]Copy Pods Resources" phases removing one Fixed the issue.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I checked the "For install" checkbox.

In: Targets > {your_app} > Build Phases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by selecting "Create folder references" instead of "Create groups" when dragging and dropping a folder into the Project Hierarchy.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this attempting to get an xcframework generated for a static Rust lib used by my project.

The build error about duplicate files can be eliminated by going into *Build Settings > Embed Frameworks* and checking *Copy only when installing* (still figuring out if this will solve my larger problem of being able to actually *call* the code).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by returning back previous project.pbxproj (from previous commit actually).

[YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yvjz.png)

Answer (score -1):

Removing the files mentioned in the error from target **Build Phases>Embed Frameworks** worked for me