React Native Twilio Official SDK Build Failed - Multiple commands produce error
I am trying to integrate Twilio voice call official package for react native. Getting the below error when trying to build the app in simulator.
Multiple commands produce '/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-ejkeyxidrdwrgyctzidcxyrfemfc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/projectName.app/Frameworks/TwilioVoice.framework'

Target 'projectName' (project 'projectName') has copy command from '/Users/mdjavedakhtar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-ejkeyxidrdwrgyctzidcxyrfemfc/SourcePackages/artifacts/twilio-voice-ios/TwilioVoice/TwilioVoice.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/TwilioVoice.framework' to '/Users/mdjavedakhtar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-ejkeyxidrdwrgyctzidcxyrfemfc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/baa.app/Frameworks/TwilioVoice.framework'

That command depends on command in Target 'projectName' (project 'projectName'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”



Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294780/833395

I have checked the pods didn't find any duplicate

Try to do https://medium.com/@tjaddams/multiple-commands-produce-error-when-building-with-xcodequick-and-easy-fix-if-you-run-into-this-6dd5a26e6f52
